# How can I get T4MVC to work with a route like "{controller}/{action}/{id}"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, t4mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website.

Following the suggestion in various blogs, I used T4MVC to change my routing from:

```
context.MapRoute(
    name:"MyArea_default",
    url:"MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults:new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

...to...

```
context.MapRoute(
    name: "MyArea_default",
    url: "MyArea/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: MVC.MyArea.Orders.Index()
);
```

This "worked", but I did wonder about the removal of the {id} segment from the URL pattern. And sure enough, the URLs have changed from (e.g.):

```
/MyArea/Orders/Edit/1
```

...to:

```
/MyArea/Orders/Edit?id=1
```

I'm really not a fan of the query string parameter, so I'd like to use the previous form.

I tried putting the {id} part back into the route definition:

```
context.MapRoute(
    name: "MyArea_default",
    url: "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: MVC.MyArea.Orders.Index()
);
```

...but of course the defaults no longer provide a default value for `id`, and so that doesn't work. If the `Index` action took an optional `id` parameter, then I'd be able to do this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    name: "MyArea_default",
    url: "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: MVC.MyArea.Orders.Index(null) // <- DEFAULT FOR ID
);
```

...but it doesn't, so I'm stuck.

Also, I'm nervous about the fact that a specific controller is now specified in the route definition. Prior to the T4MVC changes, the route did not specify a controller. Does the new style now mean that I need a route per-controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just look at T4MVC as a typing aid to avoid magic values. Beyond that, everything works the same way, so you're not any more tied to a specific controller than before.

To solve your issue, please try:

```
defaults: MVC.MyArea.Orders.Index().AddRouteValue("id", UrlParameter.Optional)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks - that looks promising. I'll try that as soon as my project compiles (it's in 1000 pieces at the moment!). Do you have anything to add on my last point - that the defaults now seem to specify a controller where previously they did not?

Comment: Hmmm, how did you get away with *not* specifying a controller before? Normally that's in there (e.g. when creating a clean new MVC app).

Comment: Finally got around to trying this, and it doesn't work. If I change the defaults as above, then it appears to have no effect (the "id" is still passed as a query-string parameter). If I then add back in the "/{id}" part to the URL pattern, then I get an error when I attempt to access my "Index": "No route in the route table matches the supplied values."

Comment: I meant keep the /{id} there. It should work, and does on my [test project](https://github.com/davidebbo/T4MVCSampleApp). Not sure what is different about yours. You still have that unsolved mystery about your original route not stating the controller.

Comment: You say it works in your sample app, but I looked at the source for that app, and it's not using T4MVC to register the "MyCoolArea" route that's most analogous to my situation. See T4MVCSampleApp / T4MVCSampleApp / Areas / MyCoolArea / MyCoolAreaAreaRegistration.cs - it's using magic strings!

Comment: I had assumed that the Area part was not that relevant here, since the main focus of the question was on the 'id' handling, which should work the same whether it's in an area or not.

Comment: Ok, I added a sample [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/T4MVCSampleApp/blob/12334ee10c56060f9fb67340f52b2b2f686ad66a/T4MVCSampleApp/Areas/MyCoolArea/MyCoolAreaAreaRegistration.cs#L17-L21). But I also found what's most likely causing you trouble: you need to use `MapRouteArea` instead of `MapRoute` when dealing with an Area.